# Split string at first delimiter followed by substring containing at least one digit

Tags: r, regex

I wish to split institution names from addresses in a vector. My heuristic is that the address is the right-hand side of the string starting from the first comma followed by a substring containing a digit.

So the raw data looks like this:

```
a <- c("CATHOLIC UNIV KOREA, COLL MED, DEPT LAB MED, SEOUL, SOUTH KOREA", 
"UNIV ULSAN, DEPT LAB MED, COLL MED, 88 OLYMP RO 43 GIL, SEOUL 05505, SOUTH KOREA", 
"UNIV ULSAN, DEPT INTERNAL MED, COLL MED, SEOUL, SOUTH KOREA", 
"ASAN MED CTR, 88 OLYMP RO 43 GIL, SEOUL 05505, SOUTH KOREA", 
"YONSEI UNIV, COLL MED, SEVERANCE HOSP, DEPT LAB MED, 50 YONSEI RO, SEOUL 03722, SOUTH KOREA", 
"KWANGWOON UNIV, DEPT ELECT MAT ENGN, SEOUL 139701, SOUTH KOREA",
"YG 1 CO LTD, 68 CHONGCHON DONG, INCHEON 430030, SOUTH KOREA")
```

And I want:

```
"CATHOLIC UNIV KOREA, COLL MED, DEPT LAB MED, SEOUL, SOUTH KOREA" ""
"UNIV ULSAN, DEPT LAB MED, COLL MED"                              "88 OLYMP RO 43 GIL, SEOUL 05505, SOUTH KOREA"
"UNIV ULSAN, DEPT INTERNAL MED, COLL MED, SEOUL, SOUTH KOREA"     ""
"ASAN MED CTR"                                                    "88 OLYMP RO 43 GIL, SEOUL 05505, SOUTH KOREA"
"YONSEI UNIV, COLL MED, SEVERANCE HOSP, DEPT LAB MED"             "50 YONSEI RO, SEOUL 03722, SOUTH KOREA"
"KWANGWOON UNIV, DEPT ELECT MAT ENGN"                             "SEOUL 139701, SOUTH KOREA"
""                                                                "YG 1 CO LTD, 68 CHONGCHON DONG, INCHEON 430030, SOUTH KOREA"
```

EDIT 1: I've reworded my question in a more systematic way.

EDIT 2: The digit may occur before the first delimiter: I have added such a value at the end of the example data.

Comment: The logic is not clear to me. Can you explain your output for "UNIV ULSAN, DEPT LAB MED, COLL MED, 88 OLYMP RO 43 GIL, SEOUL 05505, SOUTH KOREA" and "ASAN MED CTR, 88 OLYMP RO 43 GIL, SEOUL 05505, SOUTH KOREA".

Comment: In both cases, the string is split around the first comma which is followed by a string containing at least one digit. In these cases, the digit appears immediately after the comma (plus space), as in the case of `"YONSEI UNIV, COLL MED, SEVERANCE HOSP, DEPT LAB MED, 50 YONSEI RO, SEOUL 03722, SOUTH KOREA"`. In the case of `"ASAN MED CTR, 88 OLYMP RO 43 GIL, SEOUL 05505, SOUTH KOREA"`, the digit appears after a few non-digit characters.

Comment: Sorry, I made a copy/paste mistake. The last value in the above comment should read `"KWANGWOON UNIV, DEPT ELECT MAT ENGN, SEOUL 139701, SOUTH KOREA"`. In that case, the digit only appears after a few non-digit characters (`"SEOUL"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#extract left-hand side (name)
al <- trimws(sub("[[:punct:]]+$", "", sub("(^|[^0-9]+,)([^,]+[0-9].*)$", "\\1", a)))
[1] "CATHOLIC UNIV KOREA, COLL MED, DEPT LAB MED, SEOUL, SOUTH KOREA"
[2] "UNIV ULSAN, DEPT LAB MED, COLL MED"                             
[3] "UNIV ULSAN, DEPT INTERNAL MED, COLL MED, SEOUL, SOUTH KOREA"    
[4] "ASAN MED CTR"                                                   
[5] "YONSEI UNIV, COLL MED, SEVERANCE HOSP, DEPT LAB MED"            
[6] "KWANGWOON UNIV, DEPT ELECT MAT ENGN"
[7] ""

#extract right-hand side (address)
ar <- ifelse(grepl("[0-9]", a), trimws(sub("(^|[^0-9]+,)([^,]+[0-9].*)$", "\\2", a)), "")
[1] ""
[2] "88 OLYMP RO 43 GIL, SEOUL 05505, SOUTH KOREA"                   
[3] ""    
[4] "88 OLYMP RO 43 GIL, SEOUL 05505, SOUTH KOREA"                   
[5] "50 YONSEI RO, SEOUL 03722, SOUTH KOREA"                         
[6] "SEOUL 139701, SOUTH KOREA"
[7] "YG 1 CO LTD, 68 CHONGCHON DONG, INCHEON 430030, SOUTH KOREA"

#Combine names and addresses in a dataframe
data.frame(al, ar, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

EDIT 1: Now works also when digit appears before first comma, using same regex for both left and right hand-sides.

EDIT 2: Remove trailing comma from left-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Base R regex solution:

```
b <-
  within(data.frame(
    lhs = gsub("\\,\\s+\\d.*|\\,\\s+\\w+\\s+\\d+.*|^\\w+\\s+\\d+.*", "", a)
  ), {
    rhs <-
      sapply(seq_along(lhs), function(i) {
        ifelse(grepl("\\d+", a[i]),
               ifelse(lhs[i] == "", a[i],
                      gsub(paste0(lhs[i], ", "),
                           "",
                           a[i])), "")
      })
  })
```

Data:

```
a <- c("CATHOLIC UNIV KOREA, COLL MED, DEPT LAB MED, SEOUL, SOUTH KOREA", 
       "UNIV ULSAN, DEPT LAB MED, COLL MED, 88 OLYMP RO 43 GIL, SEOUL 05505, SOUTH KOREA", 
       "UNIV ULSAN, DEPT INTERNAL MED, COLL MED, SEOUL, SOUTH KOREA", 
       "ASAN MED CTR, 88 OLYMP RO 43 GIL, SEOUL 05505, SOUTH KOREA", 
       "YONSEI UNIV, COLL MED, SEVERANCE HOSP, DEPT LAB MED, 50 YONSEI RO, SEOUL 03722, SOUTH KOREA", 
       "KWANGWOON UNIV, DEPT ELECT MAT ENGN, SEOUL 139701, SOUTH KOREA",
       "YG 1 CO LTD, 68 CHONGCHON DONG, INCHEON 430030, SOUTH KOREA")
```

Comment: This answer does not extract the right address for "KWANGWOON UNIV, DEPT ELECT MAT ENGN, SEOUL 139701, SOUTH KOREA" which should be "SEOUL 139701, SOUTH KOREA" instead of "139701, SOUTH KOREA".

Comment: @syre please see edited solution, thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: This answer does not work for `"YG 1 CO LTD, 68 CHONGCHON DONG, INCHEON 430030, SOUTH KOREA"`.

Comment: @syre edited to reflect the edit to the underlying data.